# MS SQL - SUM column values for distinct values in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's assume I have a table with employee production

| id | work_order | product | qty | qty_to_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | ABC | 25 |  |
| 2 | 200 | ABC | 25 |  |

i would like to see this result:

| id | work_order | product | qty | qty_to_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | ABC | 25 | 25 |
| 2 | 200 | ABC | 25 | 0 |

I want to place a value of qty in qty_to_sum column based on distinct work_order and product columns combination, so when I get the first distinct result I place a value in qty_to_sum and each row with the same work_order and product will get 0.
I tried to use row_number but I didn't get what I needed.

Comment: _I tried to use row_number_ Show your "attempt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function then use `CASE WHEN` to judgment the first per `work_order`,`product` will show the value, others will display 0

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY work_order,product  ORDER BY id)  = 1 THEN qty ELSE 0 END) 'qty_to_sum'
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec978/1/0)**:

```
| id | work_order | product | qty | qty_to_sum |
|----|------------|---------|-----|------------|
|  1 |        200 |     ABC |  25 |         25 |
|  2 |        200 |     ABC |  25 |          0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SUM with a window OVER, like :

```
SUM(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY work_order, product ORDER BY id DESC)
```